# Java Regex to convert LDAP path to distinguished name

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a list of group names in below format:

> g=group1/cat_red/cat_top/domain1
>   g=group2/cat_light/cat_green/cat_down/domain2

and I want to extract the distinguishedNames like this:

> CN=group1,OU=cat_red,OU=cat_top,DC=domain1,DC=intertnal
>   CN=group2,OU=cat_light,OU=cat_green,OU=cat_down,DC=domain2,DC=intertnal

The paths are of different lengths. Can it be done by regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't have many edge cases, this works for those you have:

```
String name = ldap.replaceAll("^g", "CN").replaceAll("/([^/]+$)", ",DC=$1,DC=internal").replace("/", ",OU=");    // a missing comma added
```

Comment: that works fine, but i was looking for a single expression regex. Is that possible at all?

Comment: @PyGuy not possible, because java doesn't support conditional replacement terms.

Answer (score 1):

First replace the occurrence of `g=` at the head of the string with `CN=`.

Then find all slashes followed by allowable characters then another slash, that is, `\(?=\w\)` and replace the first slash with `,OU=`. Use lookahead for everything after the first slash, that's what the `?=` does.

Then find the slash followed by allowable characters and end of string, replace the slash with `,DC=` and append the `DC=internal` (which you spelled wrong, I presume).